# Python - regex on input string to format whitespace in filenames

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, whitespace

Trying to write a regex in Python that will take filenames that are incorrectly formatted, and fix them.  This works on some of the strings (f0-f5) but not others:

```
import re, os, sys

f0 = '201308 - (82608) - MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Klingler, Lee.txt'
f1 = '201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L-007-course Name 1 - last, first.txt'
f2 = '@ @ @ @ @ @ 123 abc - a-1 - b-2.txt'
f3 = '201308-(82609)     -MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus  -  Klingler, Lee.txt'
f4 = '201308    -    (12345)-ABC 2233L-007-course Name-last, first.txt'
f5 = '201308-(12345)-ABC 2233L-007-course Name-last, first.txt'

term = "201308"
res1 = re.search(term + '\s-\s\(\d{5}\)\s-\s\w{3}\s\d{4}\w?-\d{3}-[^\.]+\s-\s[^\.]+\.txt', f1)
r1 = re.sub(r"(?<=[0-9]) ?- ?(?=[^0-9a-zA-Z])", " - ", re.sub(r"(?<=[^0-9]) ?- ?(?=[0-9a-zA-Z])", " - ", f4))
r2 = re.sub(r"(?<=[0-9]) *- *(?=[^0-9a-zA-Z])", " - ", re.sub(r"(?<=[^0-9]) *- *(?=[0-9a-zA-Z])", " - ", f4)) # success!!
if r1: print r1
else: print "error on %s"%r1
if r2: print r2
else: print "error on %s"%r2
```

As you can see from f0-f5 (except f2 which is just an outlier), this is intended to take strings with improper whitespace between hyphens (which divide up the elements here), and reform it back together as shown in `r1` and `r2`.  The `res1` is the regex to match the properly formatted string.

Here's an example of the proper filename (improper names have varying whitespace):

`201308 - (82608) - MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Klingler, Lee.txt`

For the same reason, `re.split()` cannot be used because it will not normalize the whitespace between hyphens to whatever is needed at that point in the string.

f3 can be fixed by `r2`, but f4 and f5 are really the kinds of errors that I need to correct for.  The whitespace before and after hyphens (only) needs to match exactly the proper format.

EDIT:

Thank you to everyone who wrote in with a solution. You definitely taught me a lot today, and rest assured that you have single-handedly improved at least 1 person's ability to program.  Icing on the cake is helping me with a problem that has frustrated me for a week now.  Unfortunately, only 1 can be chosen accepted answer, that's the hard part.

Very close call, but used the regex only because time complexity may not be as big of an issue here with <500 files total (and divided into directories so not much to slow each pass of the program which is user input driven anyhow).  Also, I just learned so much from the regex, my head is spinning from how much info I'm getting here.

Comment: Try splitting up what you want into a series of steps that you can describe verbally. Looking from your examples, my steps are like this: 1) Clean up all whitespace 2) Put space before and after hyphens which are between regex1 and regex2 3) Put space after comma of last name. Is this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think you can take the regex you currently have for the valid file name and tweak it a little:

```
\s*-\s*(\(\d{5}\))\s*-\s*(\w{3}\s\d{4}\w?-\d{3}-(?:[^.\s]|\b\s\b)+)\s*-\s*([^.]+\.txt)$
```

And use a replace of:

```
 - \1 - \2 - \3
```

(there's also a space before the first hyphen)

I added some `*` to the `\s` and used `(?:[^.\s]|\b\s\b)+)` (to allow for the spaces within the course name) instead of `[^\.]` (note that the period in `[^\.]` need not be escaped).

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/kK7rN9).

```
>>> f4 = '201308    -    (12345)-ABC 2233L-007-course Name-last, first.txt'
>>> print(re.sub(r'\s*-\s*(\(\d{5}\))\s*-\s*(\w{3}\s\d{4}\w?-\d{3}-(?:[^.\s]|\b\s\b)+)\s*-\s*([^.]+\.txt)$', r' - \1 - \2 - \3', f4)
201308 - (82609) - MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Klingler, Lee.txt
```

Comment: I'm not finding this on Google, what does the `- \1 - \2 - \3` mean? The `- \1 - \2` represent groups like between hyphens or...?

Comment: @stackuser `\1` is a backreference to the first captured group in the regex using parentheses. See that `(\(\d{5}\))` the `\(\d{5}\)` part is stored in `\1`. You can find it in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and look for `\number` for the details there. Each pattern wrapped between parens gets stored in a variable and the number of the variable is the order in which they occur. So that if I capture 3 parts, I get 3 variables from `\1` to `\3`.

Comment: @stackuser Basically in that re.sub, I'm capturing everything that's not a `\s*-\s*` and placing them back between correctly spaced hyphens.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out time complexity on this. As in the parser comments below, I've got let's say 50-100 files per directory and a few directories. Do you think big O matters here? In the other comments, I'm getting that the parser is linear whereas a regex can range from linear to exponential in time complexity.

Comment: @stackuser Compiling the regex before using it in re.sub will speed things up significantly. The regex shouldn't take too long, there's not that much back tracking as I see it. But now of course there might be edge cases where it mightn't work as expected, just like how the parser can mishandle the same edge cases; and what I see right now as examples of edge cases is when you have hyphens in the course name, where both the parser and the regex might fail. Both can be adjusted for this and if you ask me, I'd go for the parser after it is fixed for the edge case.

Comment: @stackuser By the way, BartoszKP's current parser adds a space at the end of the file name (it can be stripped easily though).

Answer (score 2):

For such a complicated task it would be simpler to write a simple parser. Even without writing parser something like this still seems easier to manage then regexps:

```
f0 = '201308 - (82608) - MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Klingler, Lee.txt'
f1 = '201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L-007-course Name 1 - last, first.txt'
f2 = '@ @ @ @ @ @ 123 abc - a-1 - b-2.txt'
f3 = '201308-(82609)     -MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus  -  Klingler, Lee.txt'
f4 = '201308    -    (12345)-ABC 2233L-007-course Name-last, first.txt'
f5 = '201308-(12345)-ABC 2233L-007-course Name-last, first.txt'

for f in [f0,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5]:
    parts = f.split('-')
    parts = [p.strip() for p in parts]
    for i in range(0, len(parts)):
        if i == 0 or i == 4:
            parts[i] = parts[i] + ' '
        elif i == 2:
            parts[i] = ' ' + parts[i]
        elif i != 3:
            parts[i] = ' ' + parts[i] + ' '

    result = "-".join(parts)

    print result
```

Few of such ifs should work if input data is mostly similar to what you've presented.

Result:

```
201308 - (82608) - MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Klingler, Lee.txt 
201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L-007-course Name 1 - last, first.txt 
@ @ @ @ @ @ 123 abc - a - 1-b-2.txt 
201308 - (82609) - MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Klingler, Lee.txt 
201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L-007-course Name - last, first.txt 
201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L-007-course Name - last, first.txt
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the parser uses more or less resources than the regex below.  This is part of a larger program that will go through a directory, match the proper filenames (as in `res1` in my OP), and then parse/regex anything with extra spaces to the proper format.  So, I'm wondering which would be better to use in this case...

Comment: @stackuser Computational complexity of a regexp can vary from `O(n)` to `O(2^m)` (n - string length, m - regexp length), whereas this solution is `O(n)`. I'm not sure, but simple recursive descending parser is also `O(n)`. How large is your program doesn't matter - what matters is whether the file count to process is so large (or frequency of executing this process) that such minor differences will start to be significant. If yes, then I think best to measure the time of these two simple algorithms on a large data set. Remember that "premature optimization is the root of all evil" ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `findall()` instead of a `sub()`, like:

```
re.findall(r'^(\d+)\s*-\s*(\(\d+\))\s*-\s*(.*?)\s*-\s*(\S+,.*)$', string)
```

A demostration:

```
import re, os, sys

f0 = '201308 - (82608) - MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Klingler, Lee.txt'
f1 = '201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L-007-course Name 1 - last, first.txt'
f2 = '@ @ @ @ @ @ 123 abc - a-1 - b-2.txt'
f3 = '201308-(82609)     -MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus  -  Klingler, Lee.txt'
f4 = '201308    -    (12345)-ABC 2233L-007-course Name-last, first.txt'
f5 = '201308-(12345)-ABC 2233L-007-course Name-last, first.txt'

for f in [f0, f1, f3, f4, f5]:
    print(' - '.join(str(elem) for elem in re.findall(r'^(\d+)\s*-\s*(\(\d+\))\s*-\s*(.*?)\s*-\s*(\S+,.*)$', f)[0]))
```

It yields:

```
201308 - (82608) - MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Klingler, Lee.txt
201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L-007-course Name 1 - last, first.txt
201308 - (82609) - MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Klingler, Lee.txt
201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L-007-course Name - last, first.txt
201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L-007-course Name - last, first.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work out for you?
I didn't understand if the hyphens are the only thing bothering you.

```
' '.join(filter(lambda x: x!='', f4.replace('-',' - ').split(' ')))
```

Example:

```
>>> f1 = '201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L-007-course Name 1 - last, first.txt'
>>> f2 = '@ @ @ @ @ @ 123 abc - a-1 - b-2.txt'
>>> f3 = '201308-(82609)     -MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus  -  Klingler, Lee
.txt'
>>> f4 = '201308    -    (12345)-ABC 2233L-007-course Name-last, first.txt'
>>> f5 = '201308-(12345)-ABC 2233L-007-course Name-last, first.txt'

>>> for i in [f0,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5]:
...     print ' '.join(filter(lambda x: x!='', i.replace('-',' - ').split(' ')))
201308 - (82608) - MAC 2233 - 007 - Methods of Calculus - Klingler, Lee.txt
201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L - 007 - course Name 1 - last, first.txt
@ @ @ @ @ @ 123 abc - a - 1 - b - 2.txt
201308 - (82609) - MAC 2233 - 007 - Methods of Calculus - Klingler, Lee.txt
201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L - 007 - course Name - last, first.txt
201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L - 007 - course Name - last, first.txt
```

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood what he wanted